# What do D and L stand for in the Fischer-Rosanoff convention?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, notation

In *R* and *S* configuration, the *R* stands for rectus and the *S* stands for sinister. Similarly, do the D and L descriptors in the Fischer-Rosanoff convention stand for something?

Comment: Your question title is inconsistent with the text. See e.g. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/dl-vs-dl-notation/49015#49015

Answer (score 2):

*Dextro* (right) and *levo* (left). (I learned it as "laevo", but I don't see that spelling in a quick Google search.)

Comment: In Rosanoff's paper of 1906, the two series were designated as Delta and Lambda from which D/L was derived. For a brief history, see http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/history/Fischer/rosanoff.html