# D/L and +/− labels of glucose

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry, carbohydrates

I had just started to read about carbohydrates when I came across D-(+)-glucose. My book says that the '+' sign refers to its optical rotation measured through the polarimeter, and that it could either be + or −, but throughout the book D-glucose is always designated with the + sign.

Is it possible for there to be D-(−)-glucose?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between D and L configuration, and + and −?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44260/7951)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a given configuration there is a corresponding and fixed rotatory effect. However, the actual rotatory effect - that seen by a polarimeter - can either be + or −, independently of the D- or L-configuration of the stereogenic centre that shows up in the compound name (in the case of sugars, it refers to the carbon furthest away from the =O group).

In brief, D-glucose is always D-(+)-glucose.

Comment: Yes, infact in the case of glucose it's always D(+) and L(-), but for some other sugars like fructose it's D(-) and L(+).

Comment: The naming along D (or L) is *convention*, based only about this peculiar $\ce{OH}$ group adjacent to the $\ce{CH2OH}$ in the Fischer projection.  The rotatory effect however depends on the whole molecule.

Comment: In Emil Fischer's day, there was no D,L terminology. Configuration was designated as d,l and rotation as +,-. Today they are synonymous. The D,L nomenclature evolved from the Delta,Lambda configurations of Rosanoff (1906). See, http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/history/Fischer/rosanoff.html

Comment: This is general not necessary limited to sugars. The label is given by priority rules. The verse must be measured (perhaps calculated with some quantomechanical method).