# Help understanding this passage on optical activity

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, chirality

> Other than mirror images, compounds having opposite configurations do not necessarily cause opposite directions of optical rotation any more than do compounds of the same configuration necessarily cause the same direction of optical rotation.

I know what optical rotation is and I know what "molecular configuration" means but I still can't understand what I just wrote above.

Comment: The meaning's pretty clear (at least when I read it). I would paraphrase it as: "Compounds having *opposite* configurations **do not necessarily** cause *opposite* directions of optical rotation... just as compounds of the *same* configuration **do not necessarily** cause the *same* direction of optical rotation; with mirror images of a given molecule being an obvious exception." Give this a re-read ;)

Comment: @paracetamol  but if two molecules have opposite configurations, doesnt that mean they are mirror images of each other ?

Comment: The main confusion is with the word "compound." We are not talking about a property that holds true in all compounds. We are saying no relationship of the type described exists when comparing compound A with compound B, unless compound B is the mirror image of compound A (thus implying opposite configurations). This is just a terribly worded statement.

Comment: The issue is that knowing the absolute configuration around a chiral centre doesn't help you work out which way the molecule will rotate polarised light. So two different molecules with a similar chiral centre might rotate light the opposite way even though the immediate configuration around the chiral centre is the same.

Comment: @Max Example (If you're familiar with Fischer's D-L notation): *D-(+)-glucose* is dexterotary, while **its** mirror image, *L-(-)-glucose* is levorotary. But, *D-(-)-fructose*, which has the same "conformation" as *D-(+)-glucose*, is  levorotary. The mirror image of *D-(-)-fructose* is *L-(+)-fructose* and has the same "conformation" as *L-(-)-glucose*, but is instead, dexterotary.

Comment: @paracetamol  sorry i am very late to reply but i hope that i can still get an answer from you. Anyway, what you are trying to say is that if molecule A has an opposite configuration to molecule B which is of a different compound, they dont necessarily cause opposite effects on plane polarised light. And even if these molecules had same configurations , they wouldnt necessarily cause same effect on plane polarized light. They are just putting a line between the D/L system and +/- system, right ?

Comment: @Max Yup, sounds like you got it right ;). The D/L system (No, they don't mean "dextro/levo"...that's another thing) is assigned to a molecule based on its *stereochemistry* (the relative positioning of its atoms/ groups in space); whereas the +/- system (*This* one is "dextro/levo") is based on the *optical activity* of the molecule (which is experimentally obtained). Just because some molecules have, say, the (D) form doesn't mean they're all going to be dextrorotary (+) or levorotary(-)... each molecule polarizes light in whatever way it "wants" to; it can only be experimentally found.

Comment: Once again, I suggest you compare optical activities (+/-) of the D/L forms of *glucose* and *fructose*; it might help to have a look at the molecular structures for these 4 molecules). D-glucose and D-fructose have the same configuration (obviously, since they both carry the  prefix "D"), **but** they have *opposite* optical behavior (D-glucose is dextro, D-fructose is levo). Similarly, L-glucose and L-fructose have the same configuration, **but** different optical activities (L-glucose is levo, L-fructose is dextro).

Comment: Another useful comparison of optical activities would be between the D/L forms of *glucose* and *glyceraldehyde*. D-glucose and D-glyceraldehyde have the same configuration, **and** they happen to have the same optical behavior (both are dextro). Similarly, L-glucose and L-glyceraldehyde have the same configuration **and** they happen to have the same optical behavior (both are levo).

Comment: @paracetamol  but my book was saying that D/L is the same thing as Dextro/levo, it is only the short form of the words. If not then what is the difference between these two ?

Comment: So this means that levo signifies one direction of optical rotation (and dextro signifies the opposite direction) , right ? And the D/L system is only about the arrangement of the molecules in space ?

Comment: Forgot to mention you @paracetamol

Comment: @Max Nope. When I was in middle-school, we used "d/l" for "dextro/levo" (not D/L). When you start taking high-school or undergrad Chem, you'll realize that +/- is the preferred notation for "dextro/levo". The D/L system was proposed by Fischer to help him with sugars/sugar-like molecule book-keeping. Gimme, minute....I'll get to what the D/L system's about.

Comment: This might help: [ https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44260/what-is-the-difference-between-d-and-l-configuration-and-and-%E2%88%92 ] Also, read the comments under the answer to that question.

Comment: Yeah i got what you said. Thanks a lot man i finally understood this. @paracetamol

Comment: Glad to hear that. @Mods If I get the time (don't think it'll be anytime soon), I'll try to compress all these comments into an answer and post it here. It should make it easier for the OP and the others to refer to later ;)

Comment: Oops, I missed this comment: "*So this means that levo signifies one direction of optical rotation (and dextro signifies the opposite direction) , right ? And the D/L system is only about the arrangement of the molecules in space ?*" Yes, that's right. I went and said "*Nope*" to D/L = dextro/levo. Also, "levo" is **specifically** LEFT-polarized, while dextro is **specifically** RIGHT polarized. And obviously, they are opposite. O:)

Answer (score 8):

I believe what is causing you confusion is the difference between optical activity and absolute configuration.

A molecule with a single stereocenter such as limonene and carvone have two stereoisomers, one rotates polarized light to the left (-) and the other to the right (+). Additionally, each one has its own absolute configuration in their chiral center, which can be *R* or *S*. The thing is, *R* and *S* configurations are not attached or are, anyhow, synonyms with (+) and (-) configurations. Carvone and limonene are good examples:

[image: Carvone]

[image: Limonene]

In carvone, the *S*-enantiomer rotates polarized light to the left and so it is named *S*-(+)-carvone. The *S*-enantiomer in limonene rotates polarized light to the right and so it is named *S*-(-)-limonene. The two nomenclature systems are different since they specify distinct properties.

I hope this answers your question. If not, I would be glad to help in anyway I can.

Comment: Sorry but i dont know what the terms "absolute configuration" and "stereocenter" mean. I have tried looking them up and i will continue trying to understand what they mean after i post this comment.

Comment: do you think the guy in the first comment (paracetamol) paraphrased it correctly ? because i thought that "opposite configuration" means mirror image. If so then why wouldn't they necessarily cause opposite directions of optical rotations ?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know how much you knew about this topic so I assumed you already knew what those terms mean. A stereocenter in organic chemistry is a carbon atom that can originate chirality or is chiral (i.e has 4 different substituents attached to it). If the molecule has only 1 stereocenter (or chiral carbon), it will have 2 optical isomers, one is called R, the other S (a nice introductory video by Khan Academy about this can be found at https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/stereochemistry-topic/chirality-r-s-system/v/introduction-to-chirality )

Comment: What i am not understanding about stereocenters is how every website is saying that exchanging two groups connected to the stereocenter leads to the formation of a stereoisomer but i can see the molecule looking the same if we just rotated it.

Comment: Chirality is a broad concept that is present not only in organic chemistry, but in everything, from inorganic compounds to everyday structures such as your hands! Something chiral does not have apparent symmetry.

Comment: If you happen to have access to molecular modeling kits (those with sticks and balls used in introductory organic chemistry courses) you can create your own chiral molecule and see for yourself that they are not the same thing just inverted. If you don't, then watch some videos suchs as this one from Khan Academy, they will eventually convince you that those are different compounds :)

Comment: @Max white:" other than mirror images" reads as "except for mirror images". Then explanation is as in comment of Zhe.